# Negation of the Definition of Limit of a Function

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, logic, epsilon-delta

**Question**

Suppose we are dealing with real valued functions $f(x)$ of one real variable $x$. We say that the limit of $f(x)$ at point $a$ exists and equals to $L$ if and only if

$$\exists L:\left( {\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists \delta  > 0:\left( {\forall x,0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta  \implies \left| {f(x) - L} \right| < \varepsilon } \right)} \right)$$

and show this by the symbolism

$$\mathop {\lim f(x)}\limits_{x \to a}  = L$$

Now, what do we say when we want to state that the limit of function $f(x)$ does not exist at $a$? In fact, what is the negation of the above statement? I am interested to obtain the negation with a **step by step** approach using **tautologies** in **logic**. To be specific, I want to start from

$$\neg \left[ {\exists L:\left( {\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists \delta  > 0:\left( {\forall x,0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta  \implies \left| {f(x) - L} \right| < \varepsilon } \right)} \right)} \right]$$

and then go through it to get the final form of negation (See the example below).

---

**My Thought**

I just wrote down the two following negations **without** going through a **step by step** approach.

$$\forall L,\exists \varepsilon  > 0:\left( {\forall \delta  > 0,\exists x:0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta  \implies \left| {f(x) - L} \right| \ge \varepsilon } \right)$$

or

$$\nexists L:\left( {\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists \delta  > 0:\left( {\forall x,0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta  \implies \left| {f(x) - L} \right| < \varepsilon } \right)} \right)$$

I want to know weather these are true or not.

---

**Example**

I will give an example of what I mean by a **step by step** approach. Consider the following statement

$${P}\implies R$$

I want to take a **step by step** approach to obtain the negation of the above statement. Here is what they usually do in logic

\begin{align}
\, \neg \left( {P \implies R} \right) &\iff \neg \left( {\neg P \vee R} \right) & \text{Conditional  Disjunction} \\
\qquad \qquad \quad &\iff \neg \neg P \wedge \neg R & \text{Demorgan's  Law} \\
\qquad \qquad \quad &\iff P \wedge \neg R & \text{Double  Negation}
\end{align}

Comment: Try to negate the following first: $\forall L \exists M\colon L<M$. You might already spot a mistake in the above.

Comment: I am asking if there is a mistake! :) Please spot any mistakes if it exists. Thanks.

Comment: It is a bit non-standard to write $\forall x \in A \rightarrow P$ where $A$ is a set and $P$ is a formula.

Comment: From [FAQ about tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/128#128): *Try to avoid creating new tags. Instead, check if there is some synonym that already has a popular tag.* It's not easy to keep balance between too specific tags and not having enough tags, but it is always good to search first and to ask yourself, whether newly created tag is not too specific. (Of course, you can disagree with the removal of the tag you've created, and there is possibility for further discussion, if needed.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first negation is almost completely right.  You forgot to negate the implication at the end.

Remember that the negation of an "if, then" statement is **not** an "if, then" statement.  $A \implies B$ has negation "$A \land \neg B$" (read: $A$ and *not* $B$).

So, "if the sky is blue, then I love cheese" has negation "the sky is blue and I do not love cheese."

We say $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ if $$\forall \epsilon > 0\text{, }\exists \delta > 0 \text{ such that }\forall x\text{, }|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$$  Then the negation of this is: $$\exists \epsilon > 0\text{ such that }\forall \delta > 0\text{, }\exists x\text{ such that }|x - a| < \delta \text{ **and** }|f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon.$$

---

**UPDATE**  Here is how to negate the following statement step by step

> Negation of "$\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ **exists**", i.e., $$\exists L\forall \epsilon > 0\exists \delta > 0\forall x:(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon).$$

We say $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ **does not exist** if:

$\neg[\exists L\forall \epsilon > 0\exists \delta > 0\forall x:(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)]$

$\forall L \neg[\forall\epsilon > 0\exists \delta > 0\forall x:(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)]$

$\forall L\exists \epsilon > 0\neg[\exists \delta > 0\forall x:(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)]$

$\forall L\exists \epsilon > 0\forall \delta > 0\neg[\forall x:(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)]$

$\forall L\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0\exists x: \neg[|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon]$

$\forall L\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0\exists x: |x - a| < \delta \land \neg(|f(x) - L| < \epsilon)$ (Negation of implication)

$\forall L\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0\exists x: |x - a| < \delta \land |f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon$

Comment: @H.R. I'm afraid I can't help because even though I know how to negate it step by step, but I am unfamiliar with the names of the tautologies I would be using.  If you would like to see the negation step by step anyway, let me know and I will show you (no need to award the bounty to me as I would be giving you only part of what you want).

Comment: Of course I am interested. Please edit your answer in this regard. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30189/discussion-on-answer-by-user46944-definition-of-limit-of-a-function-and-its-nega).

Comment: @H.R. I updated the answer.  Is that what you are looking for?  We should discuss this in the chat set up by Daniel Fischer, but I was commenting to send you a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Your two negations are true and exactly the same. I prefer this:

$$\forall L\;\exists \varepsilon  > 0:\left(\forall \delta  > 0\to\left\{ {x|\;0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta }\;and\; \left| {f(x) - L} \right| \ge \varepsilon\right\}\neq\emptyset\right)$$

Comment: Nice simple negation form. There is also another interesting question.How do you prefer to write the definition?

Comment: Hello.  I think your answer is wrong in terms of the OP's negations being true.  The OP's negations are not correct.  The negation of an "if, then" statement **isn't** an "if, then" statement.

Comment: I have passed no course in mathematical logic but think it's an equivalent one at least for this statement.

Comment: H. R,  $$\mathop {\lim f(x)}\limits_{x \to a}  = L$$  iff $$\forall \varepsilon  > 0\;\exists \delta  > 0:\left( 0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta \to \left| {f(x) - L} \right| < \varepsilon\right)$$

Comment: @A.F.23: I think this definition is not properly stated. It lacks something between $:$ and $0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta $. And it just becomes evident when you want to express the negation.

Comment: After : should come propostion. That proposition is in the ( ), what's wrong?

Comment: @A.F.23 Before "$0 < |x - a| < \delta$" you should have "$\forall x \text{ such that}$".  Also, again, your sentence of "Your two negations are true and exactly the same" is false.

Comment: "Should" doesn't mean "must" and "prefer" means "prefer", anyway I don't think so and believe this short expression is complete :)

Answer (score 0):

If non exist $\lim_{x \to x_0}f (x)$ then for all $ L $, $\exists \epsilon > 0 $ such that for all $\delta > 0 ,\exists x : |x-x_0|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-L|>\epsilon. $

Comment: Isn't this just the first negation, I wrote above with some defects? :) I think you must add that there exist an $x$ belonging to that neighborhood not for all $x$. Also you forgot the equality sign.

Comment: No. It's good :)

Comment: You adjoint: forall x in the negation :)

Comment: I didn't get you. Please write down your answer in my notation (don't use any words for negation) and tell me where I was wrong.

Comment: Scuse me! I have corrected my answer. Both yours negations are correct!

Comment: Still not good. You must *also* negate $$|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|>\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

We say
$\lim\limits_{x→a}f(x)=L$ if

∀ϵ>0, ∃δ>0 such that ∀x, |x−a|<δ⟹|f(x)−L|<ϵ.

Then the negation of this is:
~(∀ϵ>0, ∃δ>0 such that ∀x, |x−a|<δ⟹|f(x)−L|<ϵ) ==

∃ϵ>0 such that ∀δ>0, ∃x such that |x−a|<δ ^ |f(x)−L|≥ϵ.