# The non-existence of $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \sin {1 \over x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Regarding to the definition of the limit of a function, employing a step by step approach using tautologies in logic, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473090/definition-of-limit-of-a-function-and-its-negation) it was proved that the limit of a function $f(x)$ does **not** exist at a point $x=a$  if and only if

$$\forall L,\exists \varepsilon  > 0:\left( \forall \delta  > 0,\exists x:(0 < \left| x - a \right| < \delta  \wedge |f(x) - L| \ge \varepsilon \right))\tag{1}$$

or

$$\nexists L:\left( {\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists \delta  > 0:\left( {\forall x,0 < \left| {x - a} \right| < \delta  \to \left| {f(x) - L} \right| < \varepsilon } \right)} \right)\tag{2}$$

Statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ are logically equivalent. I want to use **just** $(1)$ to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \sin {1 \over x}$ **does not exist**. However, proofs using $(2)$ can also be interesting!

**My thought**

I just know that I must find an $\varepsilon $ which may depend on $L$ and one $x$ which may depend on both $L$ and ${\delta}$ such that for every $L$ and $\delta  > 0$ we must have

$$0 < |x| < \delta  \wedge \left| \sin {1 \over x} - L \right| \ge \varepsilon \tag{3} $$

I don't know how to proceed!

Comment: Informally, there are values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that $\sin(1/x)=0$, and values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that $\sin(1/x)=1$. Now no number $L$ can be simultaneously close to $0$ and to $1$. Formally, let $\epsilon$ be say $1/10$.

Comment: Try fixing $\varepsilon = 1/4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution using epsilon-delta argument directly:**
If $\sin {1 \over x}$ has limit at $x=0$ namely $L$, for $\varepsilon={1\over 2}$ we must have $\delta$ such that:
$$|{x - 0}| < \delta  \Rightarrow |\sin {1 \over x} - L| < {1\over 2}$$
But as you can see from my last answer (two sequences) there are two number $x_1=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ and $x_2=\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}$ (there are infinitely of them but I need just two!) Such that
$$|{x_1}| < \delta \,\, , |{x_2}| < \delta \,\, ,\,\,\sin {1 \over x_1}=0\,\, , \,\,\sin {{1 \over x_2}=1}$$
So
$$|0 - L| < {1\over 2}\,\, ,\,\,|1 - L| < {1\over 2}$$
Or
$${-1\over 2} < L < {1\over 2}\,\, ,\,\,{1\over 2} < L < {3\over 2}$$
That's a contradiction if you accept :)

Comment: I like your style of proving things because it sounds like unexpected! :)
Voted Up! 
I want to prove statement (1) in question by a direct approach not contradiction.

Comment: I think you think very bad about proving things, I think all proofs are the same logically and can be changed to eachother, you want a game ha? My opponent choose any L I choose epsilon=1\2, he choose any delta and I choose x1 to show one move of my opponent is between some points, so you can change this part of my solution like this: I then choose x2 and show |f(x2)-L|>=1/2. That's it, you reach what you want with a little change in my solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Either $L=1$ or $L\neq1$. In the former case, when do we have $\sin(x)=-1$ for $x\in\Bbb R^+$? (Think setwise, not specific values). Now invert those numbers, and see that you have found infinitely many places in $(0,1)$ with $|\sin(1/x)-L|>1-\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. In the second case, instead solve for $\sin(x)=1$, and repeat a similar process.

Answer (score 4):

Many ways and hints you've got are useful. This solution is good too:

**Lemma1:** The limit of a real function is unique if it exists.
**Lemma2:** The limit of a real function $f$ at $x=a$ is $L$ iff for any sequence $(a_n)$ which converges to $a$, sequence $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$.

So if $\sin {1 \over x}$ has limit at $x=0$, for two sequences $(a_n)=({1\over n\pi})$ and $(b_n)=({2\over (4n+1)\pi})$ we must have:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sin {1 \over a_n}=\ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sin {1 \over b_n}$$
Because both are the limit. Simple calculations show that LHS is $0$ and RHS is $1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nicely done! I enjoyed your proof. But I was thinking to get it from an epsilon-delta argument! :)

Comment: One of advantages of Lemma  is to prove nicely :) they are come from principal proofs (like epsilon-delta argument) :)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is almost correct, but the order in which you introduce
your variables is confusing and may cause trouble.

You don't just find an $x$ and an $\varepsilon$ which may depend on $L$.
Of course $\varepsilon$ may depend on $L$, but $x$ can depend both
on $L$ and on $\delta$.

I find it sometimes helps to think of problems like this as an adversarial game,
like chess.
My opponent will make the first "move", choosing $L$. 
Then it is my "move": I must choose a value of $\varepsilon$.
After that, my opponent's "move" is to choose $\delta$.
I must then "move" by choosing an $x$ such that 
$0 < \left| x \right| < \delta  \wedge \left| {\sin {1 \over x} - L} \right| \ge \varepsilon $,
and then I win.

The pattern this game follows is that you read off the quantifiers from the
outside, working inward (left to right). Every universal $\forall$ is a
"move" by my opponent, and every existential $\exists$ is one of my "moves."

The problem is to show a perfect "strategy" that will win any game no matter
what "moves" my opponent makes.

Often it is helpful to give a strategy that handles some values of $L$ one
way and some values a different way.
In another answer you have a strategy that treats $L=1$ as one
case and $L\neq 1$ as a different case.
My first instinct looking at this problem was to come up with
a strategy for the case $L \geq 0$, and then look at the strategy for
the case $L < 0$. The two strategies are almost the same, as it turns out.

**Edit:** Here are more details.
What follows is not a detailed proof (I want to leave *some* of this
as an exercise!) but some very strong hints.

The intuition behind this comes from the graph of $\sin\frac1x$, which
oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ infinitely often as $x$ approaches $0$
from either side.
The condition $0 < |x| < \delta$ allows us to use positive or negative values
of $x$, but the positive values will be more than enough for our needs.
Note that 
$\sin u = 1$ for $u=\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2 + 2\pi, \frac\pi2 + 4\pi, \ldots$,
while $\sin u = -1$ for $u=\frac{3\pi}2, \frac{3\pi}2 + 2\pi, \ldots$.
Let $x = \frac1u$. If $u > \frac1\delta$, then $0 < x < \delta$.
So no matter how the opponent chooses $\delta$, as long as $\delta > 0$
there are plenty of ways to choose $x$ so that $\sin\frac1x = 1$ and
$0 < x < \delta$, or to choose $x$ so that $\sin\frac1x = -1$ and
$0 < x < \delta$.

So on the last "move", we'll always be able to choose
between $\sin\frac1x = 1$ and $\sin\frac1x = -1$, whichever we want.
If $L \geq 0$ and $\sin\frac1x = -1$, 
then $\left| \sin\frac1x - L \right| \geq \underline{\phantom{00}}$.
If $L < 0$ and $\sin\frac1x = 1$ , 
then $\left| \sin\frac1x - L \right| > \underline{\phantom{00}}$.
Fill in the blanks in those statements, and then
it should not be hard to think of an $\varepsilon$
that will work in each case, that is,
so that $\left| \sin\frac1x - L \right| > \varepsilon$.
As it turns out, $\varepsilon$ does not need to be a function of $L$
for this particular proof.

Having devised a strategy, all that remains is to prove, step by step,
that the strategy will "win" for any $L \geq 0$,
and also that it will "win" for any $L < 0$.

Answer (score 3):

It should be clear to you that for any $\epsilon<1$ and $L$ you can choose a $\theta$ such that

$$\left|\sin(\theta)-L\right|\ge\epsilon.$$ (Indeed, one of $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$ will do the trick.)

Then you can choose $x=\dfrac1{\theta+2k\pi}$ as small as you want by increasing the integer $k$ (take $k>\frac{1-\theta\delta}{2\pi\delta}$), ensuring

$$0<x<\delta\land\left|\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-L\right|\ge\epsilon.$$

Comment: This is beautiful. One just has to make sure to define $\text{sign}(0)$ so that $\left|\sin\left(-\text{sign}(L)\frac\pi2\right)\right|=1$ when $L=0$. That is, $\text{sign}(0)=1$ is a good definition for this purpose but $\text{sign}(0)=0$ is not.

Comment: @DavidK: quite right.

Comment: @DavidK:
It is a smart choice for $\varepsilon $ to be $\varepsilon  < 1$ at the beginning of the game! :)

Comment: @H.R.: sorry, I don't care about badges, they are meaningless to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution using epsilon-delta argument directly but like Game!:**

My oponent chooses a limit for $\sin {1 \over x}$ at $x=0$ namely $L$, I choose $\varepsilon={1\over 2}$ then he chooses $\delta$.
But as you can see from my last answer (two sequences) there are two number $x_1$ and $x_2$ (there are infinitely of them but I need just two!) Such that
$$|{x_1}| < \delta \,\, , |{x_2}| < \delta \,\, ,\,\,\sin {1 \over x_1}=0\,\, , \,\,\sin {{1 \over x_2}=1}$$

$$\text {if}\, L\notin ({-1\over 2},{1\over 2})\,\text {I choose}\, x_1 \,\,\, \text{else I choose}\, x_2 $$

Comment: Oh my god, I exactly do the second one, I did show that for all $L\, ,\epsilon=1/2$ works, I have a headache now :|

Comment: In this new edition, it is acceptable that you are proving statement $(1)$ in question directly. In fact, it is a compact form of my solution with different choices of $\varepsilon $ and $x$. Good Job! :)

Comment: Dorost bood faghat alan to fahmidi :) oon moghe ham ke migi folan farz ro kardi knob age oontori nabashe chizi baraye esbat nadarim va az hamun moghe to be khastat residi.

Comment: Chon behtarin Javan entekhab kardi nemikonam :) taze tekrari ham hast hame hamino goftan :) bashe baba sag khord.

Answer (score 1):

Here is **my own** solution inspired by **adversarial game** interpretation of **Eq.(1) in question above** which is explained in the answer by **David K** . Another answer by **Yves Daoust** was also useful for proper choice of $\varepsilon $ at the beginning of the game. Suppose that $L$ is chosen by the opponent, then at this stage its my turn to choose $\varepsilon $. What $\varepsilon $ shall I choose? Let me consider

$$\varepsilon  = {1 \over 3}\tag{1}$$

In the next step, the opponent will choose a $\delta $. Now I may choose **one** $x$ such that

$$0 < \left| x \right| < \delta  \wedge \left| {\sin {1 \over x} - L} \right| \ge \varepsilon\tag{2}$$

holds and fortunately there are many such $x$'s. So my choice of $x$'s can be

$$x = \left\{ \matrix{
  \text{any}\,\,x:\left| {\sin {1 \over x}} \right| \ge {1 \over 3} \wedge 0 < \left| x \right| < \delta \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,L = 0 \hfill \cr 
  \text{any}\,\,x:\left| {\sin {1 \over x} - L} \right| \ge {1 \over 3} \wedge \,0 < \left| x \right| < \delta \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,L \ne 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\tag{3}$$

To be more specific I can choose

$$x_n = \left\{ \matrix{
  {1 \over {{\pi  \over 2} + 2n\pi }}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,L = 0 \hfill \cr 
  {1 \over { - {{\left| L \right|} \over L}{\pi  \over 2} + 2n\pi }}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,L \ne 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\tag{4}$$

By this choice of $x$, the first conditions, i.e., $\left| {\sin {1 \over x}} \right| \ge {1 \over 3}$ and $\left| {\sin {1 \over x} - L} \right| \ge {1 \over 3}$, will be satisfied for sure. It remains to satisfy $0 < \left| x_n \right| < \delta $. We can do this by choosing enough large $n$. To be more exact, we can prove

$$\forall \delta  > 0,\exists n:n \ge N \to \left| {{x_n}} \right| < \delta\tag{5} $$

Hence, no matter what the opponent choose I can ensure by my proper choices that $(2)$ will happen. So I will win anyway which means that the limit does not exist! :)

Comment: The three cases $|L|>1$, $|L|=1$, $|L|<1$ seem to be a good way of organizing your strategy. It's a little unclear how you choose $\varepsilon$ for the case $|L|=1$, because it seems to depend on the value of $\sin\frac1x$, but we can't choose $x$ until after we know $\delta$ (otherwise we might choose too large a value). The case $|L|<1$ is OK because you specify that $|\sin\frac1x|=1$, so clearly then $\varepsilon=1-|L|$. I think if you just choose a particular value that $|\sin\frac1x|$ must equal when $|L|=1$, you can make it work.

Comment: The other slightly confusing thing was the notation in equation (5). I suppose $\forall x:0<|x|<\delta$ was meant to be read, "Any $x$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$." Usually I would expect it to mean, "_For all_ $x$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$," and it would be followed by some statement about $x$ that is true whenever $0<|x|<\delta$. Maybe it would be better to just write these sentences in English, even though it would not look as neatly "mathematical" as if you could write it all in symbols.

Comment: I can't understand one thing of your solution with this strange notation, what does x mean in (2), what does (5) mean at all?! You want a game? So read my second answer as a game :)

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks for the guide! I edited it based on the points you mentioned. Isn't there any quantifier which can be read as any!? Does it look good now? :)

Comment: Quantifiers are for making statements. In (5) we are trying to describe a procedure that will justify a statement, but the particular statement we want to justify there is something of the form $\exists x.P(x)$. So we might have something like, "Let $x$ be a solution of ___ satisfying ___," usually followed by some explanation of how you can be sure such a number exists. Or we might just give an explicit formula for $x$, for example in the case $|L|>1$, $x=\frac12\delta$ will work.

Comment: Is my solution OK now? :)

Comment: Equation (2) looks fine now. For (5), the answer by @Yves Daoust is an excellent example of how you can use a combination of formulas and language; there is a formula that explicitly sets the value of $x$ so that $\sin\frac1x$ has the desired value (either $1$ or $-1$, whichever of those is further from $L$). The formula had to introduce a free variable $k$, so there is some language afterward that explains how to find a suitable value of $k$.

Comment: @DavidK: I think it looks better in the **new** form! Doesn't it? :)

Comment: Yes, I think this looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Take the sequence $x_n = \frac{2}{\pi n}$ and note that $x_n \to 0$ when $n\to \infty.$
Note however that $f(x_n) = 0$ if $n$ is even and $(-1)^n$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: A similar answer was given by A.F.23. Thanks for your contribution. :)