# Quantifier confusion in proof by contradiction

Tags: logic

I am working on a proving a statement $(A)$ of the form

$$  \forall a :  \exists b : \phantom{\neg}p(a, b) \qquad(A)$$
where $p$ is a two-part predicate. To do so using proof by contradiction, in my current habit, one has to form the statement
$$ \exists a: \forall b: \neg p(a, b)\qquad(\neg A)$$
and conclude a contradiction from it.

I am presented some notes, where the author instead use the following scheme:

They let $a$ arbitrary but fixed, and make a particular choice for $b = b^\star$.
They work with the given $a$, $b^\star$ from the original statement, then proceed to investigate $\neg p(a, b^\star)$. They infer another predicate $p'(a, b)$, which they show to be false.
Formally, this is
$$ p(a, b) \rightarrow p'(a, b) = \text{false}.$$ The

I fail to fully comprehend this scheme.

#### My thoughts so far:

Using the distributive law of disjunction, either one of the following statements must be true:
$$\forall a : \exists b: \phantom{\neg}S\phantom{,} \qquad(1)$$
$$\forall a : \exists b: \neg S, \qquad(2)$$
as $(\forall a : \exists b : (S \lor \neg S))$ is true.
So, when $(2)$ is shown to lead to a contradiction, then $(1)$ must hold. Is this reasoning correct?
**This has been shown to be a fallacy in (Further Thouhts)**

#### Further thoughts:

Obviously, the distributive law of disjunction does not hold after the quantifiers, as the following counterexample shows:
Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $S = S(a, b) = (a < b)$. Then, $(1)$ is true. However, $(2)$ is true as well, which shows that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not exclusive.

#### Addendum 1

Since I was asked about the exact statements, I'll attach them here:

*[assumptions omitted] Then, for every $D \in (0, \infty)$, there exists an $\omega^\star \in (0, \infty)$, such that, for all $\omega \in (\omega^\star, \infty)$, $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in \mathcal{V}$, the trajectories of [...] satisfy
$$ \|x(t) - \bar{x}(t)\| < D$$
for all $t \in [t_0, t_0+t_f]$.*

In the proof, there is the following:

*[a choice for $\omega^\star$ is made][...] To prove [the lemma], two steps will be followed. In step 1, we will show that, for all $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_0 \in \mathcal{V}$ and $\omega \in (\omega^\star, \infty)$, the trajectories of [..., same as above] satisfy $\|x(t) - \bar{x}(t)\| < D$, for all $t \in \mathcal{T}$.
[In step 2, it is shown that $\mathcal{T} = [t_0, t_0+t_f]$.]*

*Step 1: To prove the result, let us proceed by contradiction. Namely, let us assume, that there exists an $\omega_1 \in (\omega^\star, \infty)$, a $t_0' \in \mathbb{R}$, an $x_0' \in \mathbb{V}$ and a $t_l \in \mathcal{T}$, such that the trajectories [...] satisfy $\|x(t_l) - \bar{x}(t_l)\| \geq D$. [...]*

Perhaps, I wrongly abstracted my question from this wording. I'll gladly await your feedback.

#### Addendum 2

I further clarified my original question according to comments. Perhaps now I have a better grasp on things myself, so let me try to give my own reasoning:

We can use
$$ \left( \neg p(a, b^\star) \rightarrow p'(a, b^\star) \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( \neg p'(a, b^\star) \rightarrow p(a, b^\star) \right).$$
Since $p'(a, b^\star) = \text{false}$, it follows thus that $p(a, b^\star)$, which is what the author did. So ultimately my question boils down to: **Did I get this reasoning right?**

Comment: Just so I'm understanding this correctly, are you saying the author is assuming by contradiction that $\forall a : \exists b : \neg S$? That doesn't look right because that is not the negation of $A$, and you have the right negation of $A$.

Comment: Yes, the author is assuming (2), which also had me sceptical.

Comment: Are you referring to me capitalizing the first letter of the heading?

Comment: No, I think @JeanMarie is referring to the fact that "quantor" is not an English word. The word you're looking for is "quantifier".

Comment: I understand. The German word is "Quantor", and English is not my native language, so I have been confused about that. I'm correcting it.

Comment: Concerning the word *Quantor* see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantor. @marc

Comment: @marc - May you share what the original statement is and how they "negated" that statement?

Comment: @Accelerator Yes, I can share the original statement, it is in a public document. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything incorrect there. Just that existence of $D$ should have been stated.

The negation can be done as $... \exists D \in \left(0,\infty \right) \text{such that } \forall \omega^\star \in (0, \infty), \exists\ \omega_1 \in \left(\omega^\star, \infty \right),t'_0 \in \mathbb{R},x'_0 \in \mathcal{V}\ \text{and } \exists t_1\ \text{such that } t_1 \in \mathcal{T}\ \textbf{and } \textit{the trajectories satisfy}\left[...\right] \|x(t_1) - \bar{x}(t_1)\| \geq D$

Just like the negation of existence of limit is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1473135/766223).

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstoand, but the negation you provide is exactly what I proposed in my question in a more abstract form as my own view of how it should be done. The question is: Can it be done in the other given way (not without additional assumptions, since I found a counterexample), or did I misjudge the original author's statement and abstract it to a from they never gave (most probably).

Comment: Can what be done? The negation or proof?

Comment: Also, in your counterexample, both $S$ and $\lnot S$ are true _only till_ values of $a$ and $b$ get specified. Certainly there's no problem in both being true because both are dependent on the premises, which are the variables $a$ and $b$. Whereas if you say let $P$ be the statement - $\forall a, \exists b : S$, then either $P$ or $\lnot P$ is true i.e. $P \land \lnot P$ is false while $P \lor \lnot P$ is true.

Comment: Regarding your first question: Yes, of course, i.e. is there a valid logical scheme, that allows for the second presented way?

Regarding your second comment: I am not sure I get what you're saying: In my counterexample, $S$ is being defined as a predicate depending on $a$ and $b$ and the statements $(A)$ and $(\neg A)$ are of the given form $P$. My counterexample demonstrates that both $(A)$ and $(\neg A)$ can be true at the same time and hence they are not exclusive, which should prevent the original author from using just $S$  in a proof by contradiction and requires the full negation.

Comment: "My counterexample demonstrates that both (A) and (¬A) can be true" No! Your counterexample says that $S$ and $\lnot S$ can be true at the same time(because as I said earlier, it's true until any value is specified to the variables in predicate). Your **statement (2)** additionally requires that the quantifiers on $a$ and $b$ be interchanged, then only it will be the negation of (1). Then certainly they'll be exclusive.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have been wrong about that. I recognize now after a good nights sleep that $A$ and $\neg A$ are truly exclusive. What I meant to write was that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not exclusive, which my counterexample shows.
So ultimately, your conclusion also is the same as mine, i.e. that the provided scheme is NOT valid in its current form, right?

Comment: What scheme? Can you please reframe. Also, just to make things clear, the negation in your book is correct (I mean the statement "_Step 1: To prove........ ≥D_" which you stated in the question)

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you for the patience.